# Is bisect.bisect different from bisect.bisect_right in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Based on everything that I have seen `bisect.bisect` and `bisect.bisect_right` in Python seem to do the same thing. Is there any difference that accounts for the difference in name, or do they have identical behavior and merely a different name?

Obviously `bisect.bisect_left` is different from both of them, but both `bisect` and `bisect_right` seem to always return the rightmost position where insertion of the element would maintain a sorted order.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are identical:

```
>>> import bisect
>>> bisect.bisect is bisect.bisect_right
True
```

In case you were curious, `bisect_right` is the original function and [`bisect` is the alias](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/4214f470f0cb9b6fef9a90758756fbc00ba95b5a/Lib/bisect.py#L109):

```
>>> bisect.bisect.__name__
'bisect_right'
```